# Loop from Parent to child component in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have a parent table which has the employees.I am using employee prop to the child table.I am calling the getSalary method .Currently In the result, this.employee.roles is giving me roles for single employee section.I would like to get roles for all employee based on the ID.The ID may be present multiple sections.

**Parent vue**

```html
<table>
  <employee
    v-for="(employee,index) in employees" :key="index"
    :employee="employee"
  />
</table>
```

```
data() {
  return {
    employees:[],
  };
},
```

***Child vue***

```
methods: {
  getSalary() {    
    let result = this.employee.roles.filter(x => x.id == employeeId);
  }
},
export default {
  props: ['employee'],
},
```

Comment: This is not correct vue code. The code is completely broken it looks.

Comment: it seems you'd like to get which roles are selected in **child.vue**. one solution is emit event from child to parent, another solution is uses global state management lib like `Vuex`.

Comment: Like this is not correct `v-for="(employees,index) in employee"`, your array is `employees` but seems you are looping on `employee`

Comment: Hi Sphinx,how can i emit,Can u please give me an example.

Comment: Hi Rajdeep,sorry it was typing error.Yes it should be employees.I have corrected it.

Comment: Your _"Child vue"_ section doesn't make any sense. The `methods` should be part of the default export object

Answer (score 0):

Their is a problem with your props. I have been working on components and the recommended way to do props is like this. And your methods should be inside export default.

you should change the type to what type to be passed as a prop.
so if employee props is an array then change the type as array. if its a string then change the type to String

```
export default {
  props:{
     employee: { type: Array , default: null}
  },
  methods: {
     getSalary() {    
        let result = this.employee.roles.filter(x => x.id == employeeId);
     }
  },
}
```